# Incomplete line when graphing multiple twoway functions

Tags: graph, stata, survival-analysis

I am using Stata to graph multiple functions. In this case, I am graphing different Gompertz survival functions; one for age `30` and one for age `70`.

First, consider the `30`-year old:

```
twoway function Age_30=exp(-exp(-3.520509+0.0762475*-34.13089)* ///
0.0378969^(-1)*(exp(0.0378969*x)-1)), range (0 50) xtitl(Years) title(Gompertz)
```

As you can tell, there is a constant (`-3.520509`) and age (`0.0762475`) for the scale parameter, while the shape has a constant (`0.0378969`).

Age is centered on the mean so that's why the covariate is `-34` (`64 - 34 = 30`).

Second, consider the `70`-year old:

```
twoway function Age_70=exp(-exp(-3.520509+0.0762475*5.86911)* ///
0.0378969^(-1)*(exp(0.0378969*x)-1)), range(0 50) xtitle(Years) title(Gompertz)
```

Both functions graph fine when on their own.

However, when I graph both, one curve doesn't complete to the end:

```
twoway function Age_30=exp(-exp(-3.520509+0.0762475*-34.13089)* ///
0.0378969^(-1)*(exp(0.0378969*x)-1)) || function ///
Age_70=exp(-exp(-3.520509+0.0762475*5.86911)*0.0378969^(-1)* /// 
(exp(0.0378969*x)-1)), range(0 50) xtitle(Years) title(Gompertz)
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem, which happens because Stata only sets the `range()` for one graph but not the other. One has to *explicitly* specify the same `range()` in *all* graphs:

```
twoway function Age_30 = exp(-exp(-3.520509+0.0762475 * -34.13089) * ///
                         0.0378969^(-1) * (exp(0.0378969 * x)-1)),  ///
                         range(0 50) || ///
       function Age_70 = exp(-exp(-3.520509+0.0762475*5.86911) * ///
                         0.0378969^(-1) * (exp(0.0378969 * x)-1)), ///
                         range(0 50) ///
                         xtitle(Years) title(Gompertz)
```

[image]